# How to deploy a spring boot application jar from Jenkins to another EC2 instance machine

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm seeing so many different sources how to to achieve CI with Jenkins and EC2 and strangely none seem to fit my needs.

I have 2 EC2 ubuntu instances. One is empty and the other has Jenkins installed on it. I want to perform a build on the Jenkins machine and copy the jar to the other ubuntu machine. Once the jar is there i want to run mvn spring-boot:run

That's is - a very simple flow which i can't find a good source to follow that doesn't include slaves, dockers etc..

Comment: Does it matter that this is in Jenkins or EC2 instances at all?  That is, is there a reason why you can't scp the executable to the remote instance, and run using ssh?  The only trick would be authentication, which could be managed using key pairs.

Comment: Can you be more specific with that 'etc', it sounds like 'I want to copy something without  using any available 'copy' command'.